# Codeigniter join 2 tables on a pivot table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

So I am trying to join Table A, and Table B by using a pivot Table C as the joining parameter. I am wondering how to do this in codeigniter. So for example

Table A has 3 fields and an ID
Table B has 3 different fields and an ID
Table C has 1 ID from Table A and 1 ID from Table B joining them.

Now normally a join in codeigniter would be

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('tableA');
$this->db->join('tableB', 'tableB.ID = tableA.tableBID');
```

This works, when Table B and Table A have a common ID to join, but when the only way to get to Table B is through Table C I do not know how to do it from CI. Any ideas?

Comment: Select from table C and join tables A and B?

Comment: https://media.giphy.com/media/M7JJpBH0NuE/giphy.gif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you the common ID in Table A can be found in table C then you can join Table A to C first then join Table C to B.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('tableA');
$this->db->join('tableC', 'tableC.ID = tableA.tableBID');
$this->db->join('tableB', 'tableB.ID = tableC.tableBID');
```